# Android Publisher cancel subscription returns invalid value error

Tags: android, google-play

I can access subscription data no problem like so:
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token

I attempt to cancel the subscription by adding ":cancel" to the end of the query
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token:cancel

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => invalid
                            [message] => Invalid Value
                        )

                )

            [code] => 400
            [message] => Invalid Value
        )

)
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel#request